# Data structure based on JSON object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

I just had a question based on MVC model, which I want to utilize with respect to JSON object. I am parsing some values from web services, and at this point, I don't want to store any credentials on the device at any given point for security purposes. Having many views controllers which can access the information with respect to this object, is it a good approach to have this object as a "singleton object" which can be globally accessed and have only one instance, than recreating the object at every viewcontroller. Also, lets say I want to create some sort of model with respect to the json object, what would be a better way to bind the objects from json to such "model"? Is there any universal way to d it or rather just "DIY" approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you can use a singleton object to store your credentials. Many people just store this information in the `appDelegate`, which serves as a kind of central warehouse to most apps. As far as the JSON modeling, if you use something like: 
[json-framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework), it will convert your data to Objective-C structures, like `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s, which correspond to the JSON structures it gets.

Comment: Owen, do you think a Parser object within singleton will be a good idea? I am using SBJson framework, and it satisfies my needs, however rather than recreating the objects over and over again for parsing, I just want to setup json parser within singleton and access it through different view controllers. Please give your 2 cents for it?

Comment: I don't see where you have to worry too much about recreating parsing objects.  The overhead for creating the parser is just a few lines of code and is a class method, so there's no need to worry about keeping it in memory. Just #import "JSon.h" in your view controllers that need it, get your data into an NSString, and just call  NSDictionary *result = [responseString JSONValue];
and pull your data out of the NSDictionary.  You're probably overcomplicating it.

Comment: Owen, How I see it is that it will just be much more cleaner code, thats all, but yea I think this will over complicate things